# More than one animation in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I want to combine two animations in css3. These two are rotate and scale. How do I combine these two to active on `:hover` on my image.

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
```

These are the two animations im trying to combine.

Comment: Can you show your individual animations, please?

Comment: the way is : -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1,1);

Comment: @GCyrillus Should put that as an answer, as you are the one that answered it and im fairly sure that answer down there was copied from yours.

Comment: This are transforms, not animations. You can get it by looking at the property names: `transform : something;` and `animation : something;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1,1);
```